# Web2py nginx and domains

Tags: python, nginx, web2py, uwsgi

Hello I am running web2py nginx and uwsgi but I am running into an issue deploying 1 or more domains. The issue is the server is always returning the default welcome application and not the folder I specify for a domain

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Here is my nginx.conf file (the relevant parts)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.cheer10s.com cheer10s.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;
        include        uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
        root   /opt/web2py/applications/cheer10s/;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.cheer10s.com cheer10s.com;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /opt/nginx/conf/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /opt/nginx/conf/server.key;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
    }

    location /static {
        root /opt/web2py/applications/cheer10s/;
    }
}
```

*cheers

Answer (score 3):

This location:

```
location /static {
        root   /opt/web2py/applications/cheer10s/;
    }
```

is only a rewrite for static files, not for apps, and I guess it is wrong, must be:

```
location ~* /(\w+)/static/ {
           root /opt/web2py/applications/;
        }
```

The line above will just server files under /static folder directly by NGINX do not touching web2py for it.

with uwsgi, this lines are responsible to call web2py

```
location / {
                uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
                include         uwsgi_params;
        }
```

and the router must be defined in the framework, not in nginx. if you want to *cheer10s* to be the default application, place routes.py in your web2py root folder. looking like this:

```
routers = dict(

    # base router
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'cheer10s',
        domains = {
                'yourdomain.com' : 'cheer10s',
                'anotherdomain.com':'anotherapp'
                },
        applications = ['cheer10s','anotherapp','admin'],
        controllers = 'DEFAULT'
    ),
)
```

save the content above as routes.py in web2py root folder and restart web2py, but dont forget to fix your nginx conf.